# Error by building iOS Flutter App on MacBook Air M1

Tags: ios, flutter

i am new by Flutter development. I have a problem by build an IOS App.
I have MacBook Air with M1 Chip (Big Sur)

My App works perfectly on Android Simulator, Real Device, Web, iPhone Simualtor, but when I try to build an iOS App, I get the following error:

```
[  +10 ms] Encountered error while building for device.
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      _BuildIOSSubCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:270:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Did you check your certificates? If you run `flutter build ios --verbose` do you get a message like "unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer ..."?